# Read data from SQLite storage in Ionic, AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to do the following in angular JS. I am creating a Hybrid app.

Check my local sqlite database if the record exists

if exists, get from the sqlite database if false then do HTTP get request to a URL (needs internet) and bring the data from there

I am new to Angular JS and Cordova. Please guide.

I am using the following code for http request

```
$http.jsonp(dataURL).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {                
        console.log("Success");
        $scope.categories = data;
    }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {                
            $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                disableBack: true
            });
            console.log(status);
        });
```

Using following code to get data from sqlite using factory service.

```
$timeout(function () {

    $scope.GetFromCache(dataURL);

    console.log($scope.categoriesFromCache);

    $scope.categories = $scope.categoriesFromCache;

}, 1000);
```

Querying it in a service.

```
getFromCache: function (dataURL, $scope)
    {
        var query = "SELECT * FROM FixedCache WHERE URI_ID = (?)";
        FixedCache = [];    


        // Execute query statement from query variable.
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query,[dataURL]).then(function (res)
        {     
            if (res.rows.length > 0)
            {                    
                        var dataItem = {
                            id          : res.rows.item(0).id           ,
                            URI_ID      : res.rows.item(0).URI_ID    ,
                            ExpireDate  : res.rows.item(0).ExpireDate     ,
                            JSONData    : res.rows.item(0).JSONData                            
                        };                            

                        FixedCache.push(dataItem); 
            }

        }); 

        return FixedCache;

    },// End select all data.
```

My problem is the following:
Whenever I am querying the DB, it is returning empty even if the data is present in the table. Please guide me or send me some links with proper and complete documentation. I checked the documentation and there is not much help there.

Comment: `Whenever I am querying the DB` where is the code where are you quering ?

Comment: Just mentioned the code I am using.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM FixedCache WHERE URI_ID = (?)` assuming your `uri_id` is an integer, if not or if it is a string, then you need to put that in a `single quote`

Comment: I do get data when I do console.log inside the factory method. Then I return that data. When I am calling that factory method from controller, it should return data, but it is not returning. It is giving empty array.

Comment: I am initializing DB in the .run method like this 

 initialSQLite();

function initialSQLite() {
            db = window.cordova ? $cordovaSQLite.openDB("Mydb.db") : window.openDatabase("Mydb.db", "1.0", "MyDB", -1);
            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE_NAME" +
                "( id           integer primary key   , " +
                "  COL_1       text                  , " +
                "  COL_2   dateTime              , " +
                "  COL_3     text)");

        };